# Different classpath between IntelliJ and mvn

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit

I am trying to run a Junit test from Intellij, which is failing. The same test is succeeding if I use my terminal and mvn.

I noticed that the classpath used when Intellij runs the test is different from the classpath that mvn test uses. I believe this is causing some conflicts during the execution in Intellij and causing it to fail.

Versions:

Maven: 3.1.0 Same maven is used by Intellij and Terminal
Java: 1.6.0_65  both by Intellij Module and maven

Anyone has any pointers on how to resolve this?

Comment: What are the differences? Did you try re-importing the whole project in IntelliJ to ensure it doesn't have some stale state?

Comment: Yes, I tried reimport. I actually found my problem. It turns out, that while importing the project in Intellij, I had accidentally activated a different maven profile. So IntelliJ was using a different set of dependencies and mvn on terminal was using a different set of dependencies.